# ViewModel granularity with Activities and Fragments

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

This question is centered around the architecture of an Android Application. **When using the LifeCycle component ViewModel, is it best to have one ViewModel per fragment or one ViewModel for the parent activity, to which the Fragments are subscribed to?**

It seems unclear to me how to orient something like a Master-Detail fragment-activity relationship without some coupling. For instance, if each Fragment had it's own ViewModel, it is unclear how the Activity should know how to react without coupling (interface, direct functions calls).

Comment: I you are using MVVM correctly, having the viewmodel both on fragment and activity would be incorrect. Ideally you only need it in one place.

Comment: That is important information. It is still, however, unclear how whether ViewModels should be contained in Activities or Fragments as well as how they should interface.

Comment: they act as an interface between your data (model) and view, pushing changes from the former to the latter. There is no straightforward or "only" way to do this however. It really depends on your architecture. In my current project, we use MVP but the M layer includes ViewModels, which are supposed to be used with MVVM, yet the architects managed it to implement this layerization just fine and each class has its own roles and is highly decoupled. Again, it depends on your needs.

Comment: I can work on a short answer if you are a little patient with me. We have a code freeze later today. After that I'll create a small example, if no one else gets ahead of me first.

Comment: Please, if you don't mind. Your insight is already appreciated. I get how things are separated, but the fragment-activity relationship seems like it adds an unnecessary layer of confusion. For instance, knowing when to close a detail fragment or passing a fragment's recyclerview the ViewModel it needs to load a list.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, there is no unique way to accomplish this, but ideally, and very specifically to your Master/Detail flow concern, let's analyze the default provided example:

`ItemDetialActivity` handles fragment creation and display, FAB and menu actions. Note that there is nothing related to user data, only "system" handles . I, for instance, try to limit activities responsabilities to navigation, and stuff you really can't avoid like menu button handling. Now, `ItemListActivity` appears to be violating this principle because takes care of displaying the list (Google examples only create confusion -IMHO- between these separation of concerns), I would create a separate fragment that contains the `RecyclerView` and its adapter.

Now to the nitty gritty. Here is a *very* high-level skeleton I hope you can make use of. Check it out, implement it, and come back if there are any questions:

```
public interface BaseView {
     LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner();

     /* perform actions that affect a basic screen status, like hide/show progress bars and errors,  
        animate views, etc. */
}

public class BaseRepo {
    // will contain LiveData instances which will postValues()
}

public class FooRepo extends BaseRepo {
    /* will contain access to database and networking functions, either by creating instance methods 
       or enforcing with an interface, it's up to you.  */
}

public class BaseModel<P extends BasePresenter> extends ViewModel {
    protected final FooRepo fooRepo; // optional, can be on concretes

    <T> void subscribe(LiveData<T> liveData, Observer<T> observer) {
        liveData.observe(view.lifecycleOwner(), observer);
    }

    <T> void unsubscribe(LiveData<T> liveData, Observer<T> observer) {
        if (liveData != null) {
            liveData.removeObserver(observer);
        }
    }
    ...
} 

public abstract class BasePresenter<M extends BaseModel, V extends BaseView> implements LifecycleObserver {
    protected V view;
    protected M model;

    public void setModel(M model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public final void attachView(V view, Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        this.view = view;
        lifecycle.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void setPresenter(P presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        this.presenter.setModel(this);
    }
    ...
}

public abstract class BaseFragment implements BaseView {
    /* generics is highly encouraged here, I've seen examples of both BasePresenter<P> 
       and BaseView<P> */
    protected P presenter; 

    /* You should bind layers here, or in the concrete class, 
       either with Dagger, reflection, or some other way */ 

    @Override
    public LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner() {
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, for every concrete screen you should create a presenter, model, and fragment that derive from the bases, and perform specifics there. I hope it helps.